# Ajax and Textbox change event

Tags: javascript, ajax, asp-classic

I am developing an entry form. In the form there are two textbox. In one textbox when I type a keyword a DIV is opened and customer list having customerid and customername is displayed.

```
<form name="form1" action=""> 
customerid : <input type=text id="cusid" />
customername: <input type="text" id="custnm" onkeyup="showHint(this.value);" />
</form>


<div id="txtHint" style="width:250; background-color:cyan; display:none; ">

</div>
```

The customer list is displayed using ajax. Now in the list I have hyperlink on the CustomerID.

I want to return the customerID from the list back to the cusid textbox when user clicks the link. Also when user hits the tab button controls should transfer to the customer list. the same trigger should fire when user hits enter button and selected customerid should get filled in CUSId textbox.

Below is the procedure for ajax.

```
function showHint(str) {

  var xhttp;
  if (str.length == 0) { 
    document.getElementById("txtHint").innerHTML = "";
    return;
  }
  xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
  xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (xhttp.readyState == 4 && xhttp.status == 200) {
      document.getElementById("txtHint").style.display="inline";
      document.getElementById("txtHint").innerHTML = xhttp.responseText;
    }
  };
  xhttp.open("post", "getemp.asp?q="+str+"", true);
  xhttp.send();   
}
```

this is the getemp.asp file

```
sernm=request("q")
response.Write "<table>"
ks.open "select customer,customerid from customer where customername like '"&sernm&"%'",conn
if not ks.eof then
while not ks.eof
    vid=ks(1):if isnull(vid) or trim(vid)="" then vid=0
    acname=ks(0)
    'response.Write empnm &"&nbsp;"& ad1 &"&nbsp;"& ad2 &"&nbsp;"& ad3 &"<br>"  
    response.Write "<tr>"
    %>
    <td><a href="" onclick="return CloseWind('12');" ><%=vid%></a></td>
    <%
    response.Write "<td>"&acname&"</td>"
    response.Write "</tr>"

    ks.movenext
wend
end if
ks.close
response.Write "<table>"
```

This is the javascript for getting customerID

```
<script language="javascript">
function CloseWind(VID)
{
    document.forms['form1'].elements[CUSID].value=VID;
    return false;
}   
</script>
```

How could i get the customerid in the main form.

This is the same when we try to do voucher entry in tally.

Comment: What is not working ?

Comment: I am not able to get the customerid in the CUSID textbox when user click the link in the generated list.

Comment: You have not written any code to make that happen...

Comment: document.forms['form1'].elements[CUSID].value=VID; I have tried using this code in the click event of the link. But not able to get the desired result.

Comment: You have not added that code in your question! Also share the parsed html than `.asp` file.. `JavaScript` could be used to manipulate `DOM` so you need to share `DOM` structure...

Comment: I have posted the whole code i.e. javascript for getting the ID

Comment: You should post `Parsed HTML` instead of `getemp.asp`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/107597/discussion-between-kash-and-rayon-dabre).